# How to set up Media controller to play audio?

Tags: android, eclipse

i have an image with some text that i have the audio for.
I want to know how i can set it up so the user can the the button and the audio will start to play.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit you question with some more details and code (if you have some ready)?

Comment: no idont have any sorry (im a noob :()

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution I think it might work.

Fisrt of all, instead of working it an ImageView would be easier to work with ImageButton.

So, in your layour XML file, select ImageButton and create one using your image with the text.

also you might want to set a null bacground for your ImageButton, this is the code

```
android:background="@null"
```

Next, in your java class select the sound and the ImageButton and set it to play your sound when clicked.

would be like this

```
        final MediaPlayer yourSoundName = MediaPlayer.create(Lotr1.this,R.raw.yoursoundfile);

 final ImageButton yourImageButtonName =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yourImage);
        yourImageButtonName .setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {



            public void onClick(View v) {


                        yourSoundName.start();
                    }
}
});
```

Any quenstion I would be glad to help

Comment: i wanted to program it with image view.

Comment: Any especific reason? Like, imageButton with null backgrouns its nothing more than a Image "clickable"